# How to count a line number with specific word from fixed number of lines?

Tags: python, full-text-search

By using the below code, I can only count the number of FBC word and/or how many FBC is there. But, I want to count a line number with specific word from fixed number of line

```
    def lcount(keyword, fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as fin:
        return sum([1 for line in fin if keyword in line])
    F=lcount('FBC', 'BLK100-199C1-J-1000-K-10.txt');
    print (F)
```

Below is the data which I want to read from a text file:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
`PagesPerBlock= 64                      
Block = 100                     
Read time= 698, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=0,

Read time= 697, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=2,

Read time= 697, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=3,

Read time= 698, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=4,

Read time= 691, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=11,

Read time= 698, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=20,

Read time= 697, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=32,

Read time= 691, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=45,

Read time= 698, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=54,

Read time= 691, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6400   FBC=71,

PagesPerBlock= 64                       
Block = 101                     
Read time= 690, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=0,

Read time= 697, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=0,

Read time= 698, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=3,

Read time= 691, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=7,

Read time= 697, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=11,

Read time= 691, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=15,

Read time= 698, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=24

Read time= 698, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=34,

Read time= 698, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=42,

Read time= 697, Cycle= 1,55555555,55555555,55555555,    Page=6464   FBC=50,`
```

---

At first, I want to read first `10 FBC-word containing the line`. Among them, I want to count that line number which contains first non-zero FBC. And, repeat the process for next `10 FBC-word containing the line`.

According to the given data & my query, the answer should be - **2, 3**
Because the 2nd line contains first non-zero FBC for first `10 FBC-word containing line` AND the 3rd line contain first non-zero FBC for last `10 FBC-word containing line`

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this using **Python**. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to understand what's the question about. simplify your input to for example:

```
header1
header2
some_data_n   FBC=0,
some_data_b   FBC=1,
some_data_v   FBC=2,
some_data_c   FBC=0,
some_data_x   FBC=3,
```

and write what output do you want to get?

---

[edited:]
so you should read all the lines, extract only these with FBC statement and then find the index of the first line containing FBC but not FBC=0

```
def line_index(keyword, fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as fin:
        # get all lines from file
        lines = fin.readlines()
        # get only lines with keyword
        lines = [ln for ln in lines if keyword in ln]
        # check where the keyword has value 0
        zero_value_str = "%s=%d" % (keyword, 0)
        presence = [zero_value_str in ln for ln in lines]

        # The first element where 0-valued FBC is not present
        index1 = presence.index(False)
        # Now we don't need this element so we switch the value for this index
        presence[index1] = True
        # now we search for the second
        index2 = presence.index(False)

        # We want to numerate indexes starting from 1, not 0, so increment them
        return index1 + 1, index2 + 1

F=line_index('FBC', 'BLK100-199C1-J-1000-K-10.txt');
print (F)
```

you can that make operations on the list of boolean quite easily to find another indexes

note that these indexes are valued from `0`, so the second one has index `1`

Comment: Sir, I want to read first 12-lines and among them there is 10 FBC. I want to count that line number which contain first non-zero FBC (The line number should be 2, which contain first non-zero FBC)

Comment: And then I want to repeat the process for the last 12-lines (Here the line number should be 3, which contain first non-zero FBC). Finally, the result should be 2,3.

Comment: ok, edited. works at my python 2.7 You will need to edit this part `zero_value_str = "%s=%d" % (keyword, 0)` to work on python 3

Comment: Dear Sir, according to your input,I want to know the first line number which contain first non-zero FBC. For your input the line number is 0 or 1 for first non-zero FBC, but I am getting two output like (2, 3). The output should be one value because the 2nd line contain first non-zero FBC [FBC=1]. please help me.

Comment: So you need to get index of first non-zero-valued FBC from EACH block? Then you should read the whole file content into string and split it by the block header `PagesPerBlock` and then apply the function to every block content. Still i think you should minimize your problem to some more simple data. for example the name of file 'BLK100-199C1-J-1000-K-10.txt' is not crucial here - you can replace it with `data.txt` and be more specific with the problem to be solved.